# internet explorer document readystate query

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, automation, mshtml

I am working on mshtml C# IE automation project. I have never seen a value for readystate for internet explorer like this:

[image]

It should be set to "complete" after the whole document is loaded but it is giving "windows-1252". Shall I consider this as "complete" and go ahead for next step?

Comment: actually this value is of charset group.. are you including meta data content tag in your page with charset property??

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be incorrectly parsed metadata

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252">
```

If you want to write automation tests then are you sure you are not better of using [Selenium](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/)?